# Starting a Nissan Sentra

Tags: battery, nissan, ignition, starter, sentra

I have a 2006 Nissan Sentra. My lights and radio are coming on when I turn the key but the car will not start, it doesn't make a sound. I had a full service in February 2016 & I am 5,000 mi outside of my last oil change. Checked the oil and it is still within the normal limits.

What can be going on?

Comment: Are there any strange blinking lights on the dash? Something which might indicate there is a security issue with starting the vehicle? Do you have a separate key you can use to try and start it? Not sure if this vehicle has a security chip within the key, but would be a good place to start.

Comment: Battery dead. Enough juice to power lights, not enough to engage starter.

Comment: Connect a volt meter to the battery, what does it read? it should be 12 volts or above, if it reads 12v or above try to start the car, does the voltage drop below 10volts when trying to start? if so the battery needs replaced.